# In ckEditor, is there a way of preventing the mention class and the data-mention attribute being added, when placeholders are added to the editor?

Tags: html, ckeditor

I am currently using ckEditor (v5) to create messages with placeholders. I would like to find a way of preventing the mention class and data-mention attribute from being added when a placeholder is added.

According to ckEditor docs, [Mentions: Customising the output](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html#customizing-the-output), when a placeholder is added, the default behaviour of the mentions plug-in, is to add span tags, the opening span tag with a mention class and a data-mention attribute.

For example:

```html
<span class="mention" data-mention="{placeholder}">{placeholder}</span>
```

At the moment, I have disabled the mentions plug-in, which means I have to manually enter the placeholders in the message editor. I'd like to retain the use of the plug-in but change the default behaviour so that the span tags are not automatically inserted.
(I cannot retain them in the message).
Is there a way to override the default behaviour and stop the addition of those span tags?